# unable to generate unique extent report i have used SimpleDateFormat Class

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, testng, functional-testing, selenium-extent-report

I was trying to generate unique extent reports with using SimpleDateFormat class.But in my eclipse work directory its showing "Test-report-null.html".
in place of null it has to show date that it can generate unique, so that i can get unique reports.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        // System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date)); // 2016/11/16 12:08:43

        time = dateFormat.format(date);
String repName = "Test-Report-" + time + ".html";
        report = new ExtentReports(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/ExtentReport/" + repName, true);
```

Comment: This is weird. Time for [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please. And welcome to Stack Overflow. PS I cannot reproduce. I get a `repName` of `Test-Report-2019.05.29.11.51.46.html`.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use  `DateTimeFormatter` and `LocalDateTime` or even `Instant`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I have used its working now tnq

Comment: Great to read. If you no longer need this question, please delete it. You have a delete link right under the question (under the tags). Thank you.

Comment: What version of extent are you using?